# nodejs: how to get original value from decoded url query string

Tags: node.js, unicode

if url contains non-english characters it's encoded in percent-decode format
like this

```
%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%AF%20Ahmed
```

in nodejs program, I need to decode this value to its original value.

I've tried :

```
var qs = require('querystring');
console.log(qs.unescape('%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%AF%20Ahmed'));
```

and this

```
console.log(swapBytes(new Buffer(%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%AF%20Ahmed,'hex')).toString('utf8'));
```

and both give me wrong value : `Ø§Ù„Ø³ÙŠØ¯ Ahmed`

the orginal value is :
`السيد Ahmed`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var buf = new Buffer('d8a7d984d8b3d98ad8af2041686d6564', 'hex');
console.log(buf.toString('utf8'));
```

It displays the expected name on the right-hand side of the terminal. You might make sure that your `LANG` environment variable has `.UTF-8` after the country/language (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`). If you are using something like PuTTY for testing the output in the console, make sure you change the `Remote character set` option in `Window`->`Translation` for the connection to `UTF-8` in the dropdown and click Apply.

Comment: actually, I found that all methods were working... the problem was in output console not in the value... I'm using Sublime Text...